# How to include a comment in an inline yesod javascript template

Tags: templates, comments, yesod, shakespeare-text, yesod-julius

In the code

```
toWidget [julius|
     $(function() {
        foo();
        bar();
     )
|]
```

I want to comment out the call to `bar`. But

```
toWidget [julius|
     $(function() {
        foo();
        /* bar(); */
     )
|]
```

trips up the C preprocessor, while Haskell style comments, i.e.

```
toWidget [julius|
     $(function() {
        foo();
        {- bar(); -}
     )
|]
```

go through to the browser.

This is a small example; my real case spans several lines, so a multi-line-commenting style would be required.

How would I comment out something in a shakespearian template, in particular a julius template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking specifically about Julius templates, the answer is that there isn't any built-in commenting syntax, and therefore the only option is JavaScript style comments. However, as you've mentioned, this can conflict with the CPP language extension.

One option to work around this is to put the template in an external file instead of using quasiquoting. Another possibility I've never actually tried is to use CPP commenting, e.g. `#if 0`.